# How to avoid another upkeep run my checkUpkeep function Chainlink

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I don't know if this is a too simple question but I'm wondering how to avoid an external Upkeep run my checkUpkeep function of my contract if, at the end, my contract's address is public and that's the only thing you need to run the checkUpkeep. I want to avoid that someone can call this function of my contract and modify the state.

https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/flexible-upkeeps/

Thank yoou!!!

Comment: anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Use [revalidation](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/compatible-contracts/#revalidate-performupkeep) in `performUpkeep` prior to running.

The best method for preventing the upkeep functions from being called when they should be is through revalidating the conditions for calling them. You could require that the caller be the `Automation Registry`, which would limit who could execute the function, but this would not prevent someone else from creating upkeep to call it.

See the [FAQ](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/faqs/#can-i-require-that-performupkeep-is-only-callable-by-the-automation-registry) for more information

Comment: Okay yes... that's what I read but I wanted to see if anyone did something in particular that worked. Anyway, thank you so much Richard.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing this problem, I found a solution that could be applicable for some of you. The caller address for checkUpkeep and performUpkeep is the registry address you can find in the dashboard to manage your upkeeps. So, what I've done is to create a modifier that allows only my registry address to run these functions. I hope this information could be helpful for any of you!